# Custom Remote Attribute in asp.net core

Tags: c#, .net, validation, asp.net-core, .net-5

I have a Country. Country has a Code. The Code should be unique in the DB, so, when creating or modifying a country, I need to check if the code already exists.

So, I created a `KeyExist` controller method (Pays is Country, in French)

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
public IActionResult KeyExist(
    [Bind(Prefix = nameof(PaysDTO.Code))] string key,
    [Bind(Prefix = nameof(PaysDTO.Id))] int id
    )
{
    if (_paysService.KeyExist(key, id))
    {
        return Json($"The Code '{key}' exists, please choice another one!");
    }

    return Json(true);
}
```

I decorated the PaysDTO Code with the following:

```
[Remote(action: "KeyExist", controller: "Pays", AdditionalFields = nameof(Id))]
public string Code { get; set; }
```

However, this method only works to display a client warning. It does not perform any server validation when submitting the form, the ModelState is Valid when the Code is duplicate, and that is not really good.

I tried to implement the custom `RemoteAttribute` (not sure this code is best solution for asp.net core)

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    // Get the controller using reflection  
    Type controller = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        .FirstOrDefault(type => type.Name.ToLower() == string.Format("{0}Controller",
            this.RouteData["controller"].ToString()).ToLower());
    if (controller != null)
    {
        // Get the action method that has validation logic  
        MethodInfo action = controller.GetMethods()
            .FirstOrDefault(method => method.Name.ToLower() ==
                this.RouteData["action"].ToString().ToLower());
        if (action != null)
        {
            // Create an instance of the controller class  
            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(controller);
            // Invoke the action method that has validation logic  
            object response = action.Invoke(instance, new object[] { value });
            if (response is JsonResult)
            {
                object jsonData = ((JsonResult)response).Value; //.Data
                if (jsonData is bool)
                {
                    return (bool)jsonData ? ValidationResult.Success :
                        new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return new ValidationResult(base.ErrorMessageString);
}
```

but it can't create the instance of controller, it needs services as IoC paramater in controller's constructor... but if I put services would mean that this attribute will be only for a single class, and all the validation logic on the controller is useles....

An other problem is that I don't get the `Id` parameter, only the `Code`, in `object value`, so, in the context there is a way to unbox the DTO object, but once again, if I convert it to `PaysDTO`, the validator would only use a single class, it will not be universal.

How should I validate my object not to be inserted when the Code is duplicate on server, and update the ModelState to be invalid ?

Comment: If you've called AddControllersAsServices in startup, you *could* use ActivatorUtilities and the ServiceProvider (you can inject, or maybe retrieve from the context) if you really want to create a new instance with DI parameters. Or you might be able to call VallidationContext.GetService(typeof(...))

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 thank you for the suggestion. I finally could obtain the controller, my problem was that I was calling the validator from another assembly and GetExecutingAssembly seem to send invalid object, but however, this method seem not to be universal, once we deal with additional fields, see the edited OP...